# Find in existing mongoose collection

Tags: mongoose

I am new to mongoose. I am working on MEAN angular 2 application. I have created basic setup require to get started with MEAN angular 2 application.

1. I have `model` folder where model schema is defined. I have properly exported this to access in other places.
2. I have `routes` folder where I am registering api calls to save data to database.I am returning the router at the end.
3. On my server app.js or index.js, I have references to bodyparser and express, mongoose and connected to mongoose. registered api routes etc.
4. I am using POSTMAN to test this.

Below is one route which is creating a collection

```
const testModel= require('../models/testModel');

module.exports = (router) => {

    router.post('/Update', (req, res) =>{

        console.log(req.body);

        let tModel= new testModel({
            a: req.body.a,
             key1:{
                b: req.body.b,                
                key2: {
                  c: req.body.c,                     
                  key3: {
                    x: req.body.x                     
                  }
                }
             }      
        });

        tModel.save((err) =>{
            if(err){
                res.json({success : false, message: 'Could not update details. Error:'+ err});
            }else{
                res.json({success: true, message: 'details updated'});
            }
        });

    });
}
```

PROBLEM STATEMENT:

Just after above route, I have written one more route to get the data from same collection. This is not working when I am passing multiple parameters. Below is the code piece for same.

```
const testModel= require('../models/testModel');
router.get('/getDetails', (req,res) => {

             testModel.find({'a': '1', 'b' : '2', 'c': '3'}).exec(function(err, data) {
                    if(err){
                        res.json({success: false, messsage : 'Could not get the details. Error:' + err})
                    }
                    else{
                        res.send(data);
                    }
```

but with no parameter or one parameter I am getting the result back when tested with POSTMAN.

```
const testModel= require('../models/testModel');
router.get('/getDetails', (req,res) => {
             console.log("req body::" + JSON.stringify(req.body));
             testModel.find().exec(function(err, data) {
                    if(err){
                        res.json({success: false, messsage : 'Could not get the details. Error:' + err})
                    }
                    else{
                        res.send(data);
                    }
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running wrong filter to find documents.

`{'a': '1', 'b' : '2', 'c': '3'}`

The problem is in your model object, you are defining `b` as property of an other property that is `key1` and `c` as property of `key1.key2.c` and so on the same kind with x.

```
{
            a: req.body.a,
             key1:{
                b: req.body.b,                
                key2: {
                  c: req.body.c,                     
                  key3: {
                    x: req.body.x                     
                  }
                }
             }      
        }
```

With your provided filters, mongoDB returns no objects, as it has no objects where b and c are direct properties of the object.

What you can do is try following filter, see if this works for you.

```
{
 "a" : 1,
 "key1.b":2,
 "key1.key2.c": 3 
}
```